# Карточка товара при нажатии

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, задача следующая, с бэк-энда получаем карточки товара и отрисовали их, приходит что то в стиле title:.... Price:.... И т.д. Вопрос, как при нажатии на конкретную карточку товара открывать модальное окно именно с данными этой карточки? в объекте что пришел есть динамический id от Бека. Решение нужно только на JS

Comment: Если можно то приведите примеры кода и в чем есть проблема, на данный момен на вопрос нельзя точно ответить.

Comment: На данный момент ваш пост не является техническим вопросом, а является скорее технической задачей с очень плохо описанным ТЗ. В любом случае это не тот сайт где размещают задачи для решения.

Answer (score 0):

после добавления слушателя на элемент у тебя будет полный доступ к тому что находится внутри просто надо взять данные и заполнить ими модалку

по хорошому надо воспользоватся делегированием событий, то есть добавить слушатель на родительский элемент

```
element.addEventListener('click',e => {
   console.log(e.target)
})
```

Comment: Да это понятно, через evt.target оно поймет на что нажал, а потом данные с таргет передавать туда? И ещё вопрос, через handelbars рендерить ток карточку или всю модалка?

Comment: @Volodymyr мы не на одной телепотической волне) но если ты про то что оставить модалку и изменять только данные то думаю так будет правельнее